# Ruby on Rails - Regular Expression email validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do the regular expression email validation example in chapter 6 the rails tutorial book by  Michael Hartl but for some reason the test "email validation should accept valid addresses" fails on a valid email address.  I tried the regex out using Rubular as suggested and it passes there.  If anyone knows why it is failing in my rails code, I'd appreciate the help figuring it out.  Thanks.

## test that fails

```
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM first.last@foo.jp]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_addresses
        assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
end
```

## user class with regex and validation defined

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :text_posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :image_posts, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}

end
```

Comment: Less of yourself, but more hassle free https://github.com/balexand/email_validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're setting the users email to the array of all valid emails, not just the current email:

```
@user.email = valid_addresses
```

should be

```
@user.email = valid_address
```